# How can I get Visual Studio 2010 to not include ANY dependencies to the MSVC runtime engine

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I need to make an app that runs purely by loading Win32 dlls and I do not want any dependencies to be associated with it. This could be done in VS 6 but I cant seem to figure out how you do it in VS 2010.

Comment: It hasn't fundamentally changed in VS2010.  There's a better question hidden here somewhere, but I can't find it.

Comment: I think the question is how to build VS application that doesn't need VS dlls. If that's the case, define static linking to the run-time library in compiler options.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the [/MT compiler flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx).

Comment: Note that this still does load the CRT into the target binary -- and if you're building using VS2010 you won't be able to run on Windows XP SP1 and earlier.

Comment: I need something that will be able to run even on Win 2K

Comment: @Matthew : Then you need VC++ 2008 -- VC++ 2010 does not and will not support Win2k.